# JS variable is undefined (not remembered) inside passed function

Tags: javascript, function, scope

i have a function that takes another function and its variables and executes that function, my problem is that the variables i'm passing is becoming undefined,

```js
function A(type = 'default_type', B = function(){}) {
  B();
}

function Parent() {
  var data = "hello"
  
  A('my_type', data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
Parent();
```

it works when i do this:

```js
function A(type = 'default_type', data,B = function(){}) {
  B(data);
}

function Parent() {
  var data = "hello"
  
  A('my_type', data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
Parent();
```

but i don't want to do this, because i might need to pass multiple variables in the futur

Comment: `B()` is the same as `B(undefined)`, passing that to your `data` parameter. Either rename the parameter (so that `data` refers to the scope variable) or pass the expected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `data` twice, change the function declaration inside your call to A() to a different name, so you can access your "Hello" data.

```js
function A(type = 'default_type', B = function(){}) {
  B();
}

function Parent() {
  var data = "hello"
  
  A('my_type', d => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
Parent();
```

Comment: that was a typo mistake please check the code again, please explain why i don't need to pass data ... why can i use it inside the passed function even though i didn't pass it , PS: i'm new to JS and the whole scope thing

Comment: data => { ... } is defining a function called data, that does NOT pass in "hello" just because you also defined data as "hello". If you want to pass multiple arguments, you can use `arguments` with `A.call(this, arg0, arg1)` or `A.apply(this, [arg0, arg1])`

Comment: i don't think you understood my question , how come when i do function Parent() {
  var data = "hello"
  
  A('my_type', () {
    console.log(data);
  });
}, it works

Comment: @HammiCloud because `data` is in local scope (of `Parent`).